# Android IllegalStateException: Bindings already cleared

Tags: android, android-viewpager, butterknife

The call to destroyItem on a viewpager custom adapter goes to unbinder.unbind() (using ButterKnife). If scrolling slow, it works fine, invisible views are being destroyed as expected. But if scrolling fast, it crashes with the following (found some answers about the same error but could not get anything from them, since the conditions were different. For example I am using not fragments)

```
06-14 17:48:54.037 13718-13718/com.areaseys.seysconecta.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.areaseys.seysconecta.debug, PID: 13718
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bindings already cleared.
    at com.areaseys.seysconecta.biwidgets.cloud.accesscontrol.AccessControlWidgetView_ViewBinding.unbind(AccessControlWidgetView_ViewBinding.java:32)
    at com.areaseys.seysconecta.mvp.view.BaseMVPViewView.onDetachedFromWindow(BaseMVPViewView.java:38)
    at com.areaseys.seysconecta.biwidgets.asbtractwidget.AbstractWidgetView.onDetachedFromWindow(AbstractWidgetView.java:69)
    at com.areaseys.seysconecta.mvp.view.BaseMVPViewPresenter.onDetachedFromWindow(BaseMVPViewPresenter.java:35)
    at com.areaseys.seysconecta.mvp.view.BaseMVPView.onDetachedFromWindow(BaseMVPView.java:50)
    at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:14519)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:3133)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:4497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:4470)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:4402)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.removeView(ViewPager.java:1499)
    at com.areaseys.seysconecta.biwidgets.cloud.accesscontrol.AccessControlPagerAdapter.destroyItem(AccessControlPagerAdapter.java:35)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1170)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1084)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:267)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:559)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

the adapter:

```
public class AccessControlPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<AccessControlWidget> widgets;

public AccessControlPagerAdapter(ArrayList<AccessControlWidget> widgets) {

    this.widgets = widgets;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {

    collection.addView(widgets.get(position));
    return widgets.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return widgets.size();
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View)object);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}
```

}

and the base class of the objects contained in the ViewPager:

```
public abstract class BaseMVPViewView<BASEVIEW extends BaseMVPView, ACTIONS extends ViewActions> {

protected final BASEVIEW baseview;
protected ACTIONS actions;
private Unbinder unbinder;

public BaseMVPViewView(BASEVIEW baseview) {
    this.baseview = baseview;
    actions = getDefaultActions();
}

protected abstract ACTIONS getDefaultActions();

public void bind() {
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, baseview);
}

public void onAttachedToWindow() {
}

public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    unbinder.unbind();
}

public void onInit() {

}

public void setActions(@NonNull ACTIONS actions) {
    this.actions = actions;
}

public void showError() {
    Toast.makeText(baseview.getContext(), R.string.error_ocurred, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

After reading about it, found this [thread](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/585) where the issue is discussed. I got the idea to catch the exception to see what happens, I guess now some listener remains hanging in memory, not cleared. My viewpager only uses 4 views so danger seems small, the app doesn't crash anymore:

```
public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    try {
        unbinder.unbind();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```